# Node.js failing to connect to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to both Node.js and MongoDB. I am following this guide: http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb to create a simple blog with Node.js and MongoDB.

When node tries to connect to MongoDB, it is failing and I have no idea why.

In my app.js file i have:

```
var articleProvider = new ArticleProvider('127.0.0.1', 27107);
```

In my articleprovider-mongodb.js file I have

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

ArticleProvider = function(host, port) {
  this.db = new Db('node-mongo-blog', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
  this.db.open(function(err){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

In my terminal I get:

9 Aug 10:48:19 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27107]]

I am running node.js v0.8.6 and mongodb v2.0.6

I have other code in these files but from what I can see it shouldn't effect the db connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens when the mongod process is **not** running or **you're connecting to the wrong host/ip.**

Do you have it running on your localhost and if so can you access it from your from the mongo shell?

Try to test it with a minimum version of an app with node, express and the mongodb nodejs driver.

I tested it with these files:

- http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb/articleprovider-mongodb.js
- http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb/app.js

And it worked fine, except for the last two lines of app.js, because of **express** 3.x instead of 2.x used in the example.

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", server.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Those are the two files I am running, just with a little addition on the db.open to allow me to see the error being generated.

I am able to connect to the mongo shell.[Here is a screenshot of what I see when i run my mongodb](http://anony.ws/JYO)

Comment: I've added the error check and it works fine for me. I don't think nodemon is the problem, but have you tried just running `node app.js` ?

Comment: If you want I can have a look at your code (pastebin or gist.github.com) and i'll test it here

Comment: If you wouldn't mind. I've included everything that is relevant. If you need anything else, let me know.

https://gist.github.com/3306564

Comment: Found the problem! You're trying to connect to port `27107` instead of `27017`

Comment: What was your typo? I'm having the exact same problem. The deamon is running i can connect via shell and http but not via nodejs... Strangly on osx the same code is working fine so I really don't get it.

Comment: I can't believe that I had the same typo and I was about to get mad.